# Google search page (https://www.google.com/) is different on Chrome than on Firefox, how to change FF?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search

In Firefox I see a section below the text box for the term you want to search for:

[image]

But in Chrome, that section is not displayed:

[image]

How can hide that section in Firefox?

Comment: Look to an extension you've added to Firefox. That is *not* the native behavior for Firefox, nor Brave or Tor, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://9to5google.com/2022/08/31/google-search-widgets/

Quoted from the site

"These cards appear at the very bottom of google.com. There’s a “Hide content” toggle in the bottom-right corner, while Google notes your zip code/city and explains that the information offered is “Based on your past activity.”

I do not see that switch on the page though, please do note that this is an experimental feature at the moment and will be changed around a bit. There is 100% supposed to be a button there.

I would:

1. Turn off location privs for google.com
2. Then clear the site cache
3. And then see what happens.

If nothing happens you might just need to live with it for a little bit. Its in the testing stage and will hopefully not suck as much in a few days/weeks.

Another reason for that switch not showing is if you have a JS blocker or the ad blocker you have, just mix a bit with it and see if something happens.
Good luck!